# What transistor should I use to power my 12v Display and control with a 5v raspberry Pi

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi

So I recently bought a 9v Seven Segment display and I want to control it using my Raspberry Pi Zero. But I realized that the Pi only supplies 5v of power and in order to power it I need 9v. I know how to configure the transistor circuit I just need help with the specs of the transistor.
[image: Here is a VERY rough diagram of the circuit]

Comment: If you know what circuit you plan to use please post it. It is not reasonable to determine specifications for a component without seeing the circuit it will be used in.

Comment: @PeterGreen Just added the Diagram for the Circuit

Comment: You show the LED power supply as "9V transformer AC" - the LED display will require DC power, not AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any common small signal transistor would work in your circuit as you shown. Assuming each segment only needs 20 mA to 200 mA, a 2n3904 would work.

Though Your diagram has the transistors oriented wrong. A npn transistor has the emitter on the low side with the arrow pointed towards ground. Flip them around.